# Can Ansible use "sudo su -" if the sudo user is not allowed to run arbitrary scripts?

Tags: ansible, sudo

I am trying to use Ansible to automate software installation and setup on several remote machines. My personal user account on the machine is locked down, but I can use `sudo su -` to become the root user when I log in manually. Once I'm the root user, I can run things like `yum install git` and similar commands.

When I tried to do that through Ansible, I tried the following to use Ansible's `yum` module:

```
- name: install Git
  yum:
    name: git
    state: present
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  become_exe: "sudo su -"
```

When I ran this, it failed with an error saying that my user was not allowed to run the command

```
sudo su - root /tmp/foobarbazblablabla
```

What happens is that Ansible puts all of the Yum commands into a temporary script file and then tries to run that using the become method/exe.

It turns out that my user has the permission to run `sudo su -`, but not run arbitrary scripts using `sudo` or `sudo su -`, and hence Ansible fails to run the above.

I ended up using an ugly workaround like this:

```
- name: install Git
  shell:
    cmd: |
      sudo su - <<EOF
      yum install -y git
      EOF
```

This works, but is ugly and does not use Ansible's idempotent check mechanism.

Is there a better way to do this in Ansible, where Ansible executes the `sudo su -` first, and then executes its set of commands in the opened sub shell? Or am I out of luck with this? I doubt that the security team will grant my user permissions to run arbitrary scripts using `sudo`. (On the other hand, it might not hurt to ask.)

This is a description of a similar problem, but the suggested solutions are the same ugly hacks I used above: https://gist.github.com/nanobeep/3b3d614a709086ff832a

One more instance of this error with a very similar error that I get: https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/53hukf/ansible_centrify_become_root/

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", 
"module_stdout": "Sorry, user username is not allowed to execute 
'/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-msylkobbkasuuxlawgqppdpjxmeqirgd; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 
/usr/bin/python /home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1474243234.94-154392424015843/lineinfile; rm -rf \"/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1474243234.94-154392424015843/\" > /dev/null 2>&1' 
as root on hostname.\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

**Update** If I run `sudo -l`, this is displayed:

```
User foo may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) /bin/kill
    (root) /bin/su - bar
    (root) su -
```

Comment: If you issue `sudo -l` what does it say?

Comment: I've added the output of `sudo -l` to the question

Comment: This post says `ANSIBLE_BECOME_EXE='sudo su -'` helps  https://www.coveros.com/ansible-privledge-escalation-using-sudo-su/

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues with `teamviewer passwd`, which wouldn't allow me to run with `become: true` either. This my task definition to setup a teamviewer password with ansible:

```
  - name: set teamviewer login to password only
    become: true
    become_method: sudo
    become_flags: 'su - root /bin/bash -c'
    command: 'teamviewer passwd {{ teamviewer_password }}'
```

This will run:

```
sudo su - root /bin/bash -c 'teamviewer passwd Th3Passw0r8'
```

As a sidenote: You can skip the `become_*`-stuff if you go with `shell`-task instead of `command`. But with that come ansible-warnings and far worse: **escape-hell** with your password. Don't go there.

Answer (score 5):

Just add this to playbook:

```
become: yes
become_method: su
```

and before running playbook export below env variable on host server:

```
ANSIBLE_BECOME_EXE=’sudo su -‘
```

Here is the reference [link](https://www.coveros.com/ansible-privledge-escalation-using-sudo-su/).

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this will work with

```
- name: install Git
  yum:
    name: git
    state: present
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_exe: "sudo su - /bin/bash -c"
```

Comment: I had tried that, and it turns out that my user is not allowed to run `sudo su - /bin/bash`. I am allowed to run the plain `sudo su -`, but not with any additional command. It might be worth asking our security team if they can grant me the permission to run `sudo su - /bin/bash` to make this work...

Comment: @nwinkler ultimately if they have you this locked down then allowing `sudo su -` is probably an accident. sudo is always better than su for auditability reasons, so if they are blocking sudo usage, allowing `sudo su` seems unintentional.

Comment: @MillerGeek What final command will be run when your playbook is run by ansible?